# How to get containers directory on docker desktop to mount it with docker image?

Tags: windows, docker, docker-desktop

I am trying to add local bitbucket runner on my windows machine that has docker desktop and wsl2 installed. I successfully added a runner to bitbucket as a self hosted linux machine, but no logs are visible when pipeline is run. In order for logs to be visible I have to mount `\\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\data\docker\containers` with `/var/lib/docker/containers` inside my wsl. How can I do this?

As I understand `\\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\data\docker\containers` is a network storage when I open it with powershell it shows the following location

```
Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\wsl$\docker-desktop-data
```

When I run docker info, this is my docker root dir

```
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
```